# Converting a daily standard deviation to an annual one

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, gaussian

This post discusses how to convert a daily standard deviation into an annualized one.

[Standard Deviation Annualized](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103870/standard-deviation-annualized)

However, it doesn't include a proof.

I've tried to prove it myself by using a summation of Gaussians and trying to calculate the standard deviation of the set, but I'm getting stuck, and I'm sure there's an easier way.

The question- why is:

$$\sigma_{\rm annual} = \sigma_{\rm measured} \sqrt{T}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to assume each sample point is drawn from a Gaussian distribution, or even that they have the *same* distribution.  It is enough for them to be pairwise uncorrelated and have the same standard deviation.  If $\  D_1, D_2,\dots,D_T\ $ are pairwise uncorrelated with means $\ d_1,d_2,\dots, d_T\ $ and standard deviations $\ \sigma_1,\sigma_2,\dots,\sigma_T\ $, then the variance of $\ \sum_\limits{i=1}^TD_i\ $ is
\begin{align}
\sigma_\text{annual}^2&=\mathbb{E}\left(\left(\sum_{i=1}^T\big(D_i-d_i\big)\right)^2\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=2}^T \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \big(D_i-d_i\big)\big(D_j-d_j\big)\right)\\
&\hspace{2em}+\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^T \big(D_i-d_i\big)^2\right)\\
&\hspace{2em}+\mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{T-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^T \big(D_i-d_i\big)\big(D_j-d_j\big)\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^T \mathbb{E}\left(\big(D_i-d_i\big)^2\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^T \sigma_i^2\ ,
\end{align}
the first and third terms on the right of the second equation's vanishing because $\  D_1, D_2,\dots,D_T\ $ are pairwise uncorrelated. Thus, if $\ \sigma_i=\sigma_0\ $ for all $\ i\ $, then
\begin{align}
\sigma_\text{annual}&=\sqrt{T \sigma_0^2}\\
&=\sigma_0\sqrt{T}
\end{align}

Comment: It was way easier than I was making it! Thanks so much! :)